# Fastest way to search a word in a word list?

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, databases, lists

I have a word list like "English Open Word List" used to create word games.
The list is in txt file with space between words, like;
aa
aah
aahed
.........and so on.
I want to search it while typing the letters in the word, like google suggestions in the search bar.
What is the fastest algorithm to do it? In any language?

Comment: You can use a trie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) might help, it stores your "word list" like this:

```
              a
             / \
           [a]   a
           /      \
         [a]       h
                    \
                     e
                      \
                      [d]
```

And you can query by some operation like `trie['a']['a']['h']['e']`, which is just array index operation. It takes large memory but it's very efficient. The complexity of the query operation is $ O(n) $, n is the length of the queried string.

Comment: Thanks mate. Trie is the answer. "Google suggestion" was an overshoot. Trie has lookup time of less than ~0.1 ms and I just need about 4 words per second.

Comment: It works best when all words are short but there're tons of words